# Do we have 'null' keyword in solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

Like other languages , Does solidity supports 'Null' keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not at the moment but this keyword is reserved in Solidity in latest document. They might become part of the syntax in the future. Check this [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords)